# Gallery view with Touch and move previous and next

Tags: android

i am creating an image Viewer and i want to go next/previous image by Touch and move left  by finger for previous and same move right to go next image. i am using gallery view, is any event or any other idea.
plz help....

Answer (score 2):

you should try to search before asking :

http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/

Regards,

Comment: With the 4.0 sdk ? Do not know, im not using it yet.